# Issue with guildScheduledEventCreate discordjs

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Does not create any trigger when I create an event

Using node:16 and discord.js@13.5.1

```
client.on('guildScheduledEventCreate', (guildScheduledEvent) => {
    console.log("TRIGGER");
    // Other code
});
```

Comment: What are your client's intents?

Comment: GUILD and GUILD_MESSAGES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENTS` intent

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENTS"]
})
```